# "continuous if" statement in JAVA

Tags: java, loops

I'm wondering is there is a way to continuously check for a condition through the execution of a function. In other words, I would like to be able to `return` whenever a condition is met, and regardless of where I currently am in the execution of my function. This would basically act like if I was having an `if` condition after every single line of my function.

The context is the following: I have a thread streaming some data. While it's loading in the background, the user can ask to get some other data (which changes the state of a boolean flag). In this case, the thread has to stop whatever it's doing, take into account the new request and start again. Another constrain is that I cannot kill this thread and create a new one.

As you might guess, the data loading function contains a `for` loop. A straightforward idea is hence to check for my boolean flag at each iteration. That's what I did so far. Unfortunately, each iteration contains a lot of instructions and is rather timey. Putting an `if` statement at the beginning is therefore not good enough as it creates a significant lag between the moment the flag value is modified and the `return`.

I was considering using a `try/catch` overhead with a manually defined exception that would be thrown whenever my condition is met, but from what I read so far it's considered bad practice.

What would you use to create this "continuous if" behaviour?

Comment: If I understand what you're saying, no.

Comment: This is a bad idea. What happens when your conditions triggers a return while you have resources allocated that need explicit cleanup (streams needing close() for example)? You should poll periodically and return when safe.

Comment: @ColinD - That's one reason why try/catch/finally may be a better idea.

Comment: @HotLicks: does "no" mean "there is no way to do it", "this is bad practice", or both?

Comment: No way to do it.  You can't define an implicit check that will be automatically repeated over the course of a loop body.  At best you can insert explicit individual tests and make them as lightweight as possible.

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely no way to do it implicitly: Java has no "magic" way to transfer control to code that checks the condition; all checks must be performed explicitly by the code of your program.

In your case it means that your `for` loop needs to check the state of the `boolean` variable explicitly, and exit when the state has changed:

```
for (int i = 0 ; !mustExit && i != lengthOfItemsToStream ; i++) {
    doSomeWork();
    if (mustExit) break; // Check the boolean flag
    doAdditionalWork();
    if (mustExit) break; // Check the boolean flag
    doEvenMoreWork();
}
```

Comment: @HotLicks Right -- I was typing this into a code example.

Comment: yep, that's another solution I tried, but I was wondering if I could get something nicer (i.e. with less repetitions) :)

thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Divide your thread into checkpoints. Then sync it with similar thread which looks for user input. When two threads meet at a checkpoint(memory barrier maybe?) they do critical operation, then they move on.

You could make such checkpoint in a loop but overhead can be bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a while(1) loop that breaks when the requirement is met.

```
while(1){ 
....statements...
if(requirementIsMet){ break; }
}
```

or just use recursion as said by @sean3838

```
theFunction(datatype param ){
if(baseCase){
   //execution completed 
}else{
    theFunction(paramBrokenDown)}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to run your for-loop in a different thread and then call Thread.stop on the for-loop thread to kill it. However, Thread.stop has been deprecated for good reason since 1.5 (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) so the only practical way is to add more if-statements in your thread to check if it should exit.

If you've got the resources, you could make the system more responsive. When you need to kill your thread, set the flag telling it to exit. You can then start a new thread to take into account the new input and ignore anything the first thread is still doing. It can then take its time dying whilst your second thread is busy doing the real work.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Interrupts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html). You can interrupt your thread throwing a `new InterruptException()` and do something else. You still have to check for `thread.interrupted()` in your loop, tough.

Your thread

```
class SimpleThread extends Thread {
    int thisMuchData = 10;
    public SimpleThread(String str, thisMuchData) {
        super(str);
        this.thisMuchData = thisMuchData;
    }
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < thisMuchData; i++) {
            getDataFor(i);
            if (Thread.interrupted()) {
            // We've been interrupted: no more crunching.
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("DONE! " + getName());
    }
    void setHowMuchData(int thisMuchData){
        this.thisMuchData = thisMuchData;
    }
}
```

Your main

```
public class MyClass{
    Thread thread = new SimpleThread("my Thread", 10);

    public static void main(String args[]){
        thread.start();
    }

    public void canIhasMoreData(int thisMuchData){
        thread.interrupt();
        thread.setHowMuchData(thisMuchData);
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

**NB:** I haven't tested it, I wrote it from the top of my head, this is only to make my point.

Answer (score -3):

Try using recursion, just call your function from inside your function.

EDIT:

Ok, obviously I should have expanded on my answer then...

```
private String functionName(String condition) {

    if (check your condition here) {
        return;
        // or do whatever you have to do  
    }

    // call your function again
    functionName();
}
```

Comment: I don't think you understood the question.

Comment: Nope, you didn't. From OP's question: "Putting an if statement at the beginning is therefore not good enough as it creates a significant lag between the moment the flag value is modified and the return." And that's just one thing that's wrong with this answer. Also, you do realize that courting a `StackOverflowError` like this is a horrible idea, right? And how is this different than OP's looping solution?

Comment: Wow... this really amazes me. So how is dasblinkenlights' (which is the top answer) answer any different from the OP's looping solution? He also puts an if statement at the beginning.

Comment: Because he actually answers the question with the first sentence of his answer, perhaps? And because he suggests an improvement on OP's original solution by checking in more places than just the beginning?